# Cómo crear tabla para guardar las propiedades de imágenes o iconos

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, phpmyadmin

Tengo que guardar iconos de varias entidades

- area
- mission
- rol

En la tabla area se guardara un icono por cada area igual en rol ejemplo:

- area 1 -> icono_1.png
- area 2 -> icono_2.png
- rol 1 -> icono_20.png
- rol 2 -> icono_21.png

En la tabla mission se guardaran varios iconos por mission ejemplo

- mission 1 -> icono_3,icono_4,icono_5,...
- mission 2 -> icono_6,icono_7,...

lo que hice fue crear estas tablas

```
CREATE TABLE icon(
id int AUTO_INCREMENT,
name varchar(20),
type varchar(20),
width int,
height int,
size int,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE icon_assignment(
id int AUTO_INCREMENT,
assignment varchar(20),
PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE icon_set(
id int AUTO_INCREMENT,
id_icon int,
id_icon_assignment int,
assignment_child int,
PRIMARY KEY (id),
FOREIGN KEY (id_icon) REFERENCES icon(id),
FOREIGN KEY (id_icon_assignment) REFERENCES icon_assignment(id)
);
```

Estare realizando una buena formalizacion o deberia cambiar algo

Comment: porque no tienes los nombres de los iconos en tu base de datos y dependiendo de eso seleccionas el icono en las imagenes de tu pagina? guardar imagenes en las bases de datos es una mala practica ya que son datos bastantes grandes que aumentan el tamaño de la base de datos y la vuelven lentan mientras mas registros se tengan.

Comment: @Alexander de echo solo guardo los datos de la imagen, la imagen en si la guardo en una carpeta y no en mysql como blob

Comment: en ese caso el titulo de tu pregunta es algo engañoso, respondiendo directamente tu pregunta de verdad, lo veo bastante bien... yo lo hiciera de esa manera.

Comment: @Alexander vale gracias por todo editare el titulo

Answer (score 0):

Crea un campo que permita almacenar la imagen en modo "binario" (**LONGBLOB**)

```
CREATE TABLE icon(
  id int AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name varchar(20),
  type varchar(20),
  imagen_icono LONGBLOB,
  width int,
  height int,
  size int,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```